# Passing data between View models using Prism Event Aggregator

Tags: wpf, prism, viewmodel, eventaggregator

I have a user control whose `DataContext` is bound to its view model which should display *Status Messages* from any other `UserControl`s which are bound to their respective view models.

*Status Messages* is an `ObservableCollection<StatusGridModel>`. Now I am trying to use `EventAggregation` in order to pass this collection from my different view models to `StatusViewModel`.

In the constructor of every view model I have `IEventAggregator` of Prism resolved by Unity. Now on `ButtonClick` in first `ViewModel` I am doing the following:

```
DashBoardStatusCol.Add(statusGridModel);
eventAggregator.GetEvent<StatusEvent>().Publish(DashBoardStatusCol);
```

where `StatusEvent` class derives from `PubSubEvent`

```
public class StatusEvent : PubSubEvent<ObservableCollection<StatusGridModel>>    
{    
}
```

Below is my second view model where the *Status Messages* should be displayed. I have subscribed to my `StatusEvent` class in the constructor.

```
public class StatusGridViewModel : ViewModelBase<PresentationModel>
{
    IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    public StatusGridViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<StatusEvent>().Subscribe(SetStatus, true);
    }        

    private void SetStatus(ObservableCollection<StatusGridModel> collection)
    {
        StatusCollection = collection;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<StatusGridModel> statusCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<StatusGridModel> StatusCollection
    {
        get { return statusCollection; }
        set { statusCollection = value; }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is the subscribed event `SetStatus` is never called when the button is clicked in the first view model.

What am i missing? Should my `ObservableCollection` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and on the setter of property I should publish my event?

Answer (score 1):

> Should my `ObservableCollection` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and on the setter of property I should publish my event?

`StatusCollection` should raise the `PropertyChanged` event, so the view knows it should update its bindings. `ObservableCollection` only works if the *content* is updated (`Add`, `Remove`...), not if you replace the whole collection.

Comment: I believe thats not the case as when I Implement PropertyChanged on Collection it stops working at all. However I may have figured out the real issue of subscriber event not getting fired primarily due to two reasons in my case.1. Due to multiple instances of Event Aggregator which was resolved via Unity as Lifetime was not mentioned[I now changed it to ContainerControlledLifetimeManager]. 2. I was publishing my event before subscribing. I think the publish event should be done after you have subscribed to the event.

Comment: `on Collection` means what exactly? Ad 1: normally, Prism registers the event aggregator for you. Unless you have a really good reason to do so, I wouldn't touch that. Ad 2: the event aggregator does not store events, so, yes, only subscribers at the time of publishing are notified.